# Why the variable "r" appears in circumferential force balance for a membrane

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solid-mechanics

I am trying to understand a force balance for an inflating membrane (reference cited at the bottom of the post) and can't figure out why there is an "r" in the circumferential balance.

The membrane uses a cylindrical coordinate system.

[image]

"s" is arc length.

I understand the vertical balance, but not the circumferential force balance.

This is the diagram shown in the paper:

[image]

This is the resulting equation:

[image]

I don't understand the following:

- T is said to be principal stress resultant, but thickness of the material is never considered here. Don't I have to multiply by the thickness as well in the first term to get force? The vertical balance did not consider thickness of the membrane either.
- I understand that T1 cos(phi) is the component of T1 along the plane of interest, and (theta) is some angle in the plane. T1 cos(phi)sin(theta) is the component of T1 along the horizontal direction, and the "2" comes from integrating this from theta = 0 to theta = pi.
  However, why is there an r? Why is it not just 2*T1*cos(phi) in the second term?

Thank you very much.

Reference: J. D. HUMPHREY (1998) Computer Methods in Membrane Biomechanics, Computer Methods in Biomechanics and Biomedical Engineering, 1:3, 171-210

Comment: Because r defines the distance from the circle centre.

Comment: But why are we multiplying the stress by the distance from the circle center? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I thought it was multiplied by length

Comment: Ok I understand now.. it's an approximation of a small arc length on which the force acts, which is then integrated for theta from 0 to pi.  Thank you very much.